# dataLayer not shown when adding geoJSON to Google Map in cordova app

Tags: cordova, google-maps-api-3, geojson

I'm trying to add a geographical feature to a Google Map data layer.  The map is embedded in an existing app developed using Apache Cordova.  The issue is that I am not seeing the callback when the loadGeoJson method has completed.

The API is included using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=XXX></script>
```

The Google Map is instantiated using:

```
        var gMap = new google.maps.Map(d3.select("#mapContainer").append("div").attr("id", "map").node(), {
            zoom: 8,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            mapTypeControl: false
        });

        console.log('gmap = ', gMap);
```

That works fine, the map is displayed, but when I try to add my data layer like this, I never see the console log:

```
gMap.data.loadGeoJson('https://www.mysite.co.uk/geojson/bigfile.json', null, function(features){
    console.log('features', features);
});
```

(See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference - find "loadGeoJson").

The file is around 9.4MB and is available on the server, and I can see from the server access log it is getting loaded.  I've checked the file and it is valid GeoJSON (according to https://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator).  I've also tested smaller files from other servers (e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinjc/UK-GeoJSON/master/json/electoral/eng/topo_wpc.json), and just loading the geoJSON file locally, but the callback never fires.

Anyone got any ideas please?

Comment: Are you loading the file from another domain?

Comment: There is no reason why this would not work if the file is reachable ([CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) must be enabled if you are loading the file from another domain). [Proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/zb05gLzs/).